# How to fix MySQL anonymous account security issue?

Tags: mysql, security

How to fix this security issue on MySQL?

[!!] User '@localhost' is an anonymous account.

Comment: Remove the user?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove the anon users? You can just use `DROP USER` to remove them. They shouldn't have any special privileges, as stated in the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.1/en/default-privileges.html) and should not be a major problem as they're only in the localhost.

If, even removing, you still can login or something, check out [this other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51452/how-do-you-disable-anonymous-login-mysql).